# How to prevent 'control' from being seen when I trigger '^WheelUp'

Tags: autohotkey

I have this painting programme, when you hold down `control` the move tool temporarily becomes the active tool.

I am trying to create two hotkeys that will increase decrease brush size:

```
#SingleInstance, force
^wheelup::
    tooltip, Ctrl + WheelUp
    ;Sendinput, {[}                     ;Increase brush size
    return
^wheeldown::
    tooltip, Ctrl + Wheeldown
    ;Sendinput, {]}                     ;Reduce brush size
    return
```

I am using a the `tooltip` command to demonstrate my issue.

But the programme notices that `control` key is held/pressed, and so makes the move tool the active tool, thus making it impossible to change the brush size. [This recording shows what I mean](https://i.imgur.com/v3yFGSK.gif)

I tried applying the `$` prefix but the programme still sees `control` and switches to the move tool:

```
#SingleInstance, force
$^wheelup::
    tooltip, Ctrl + WheelUp
    ;Sendinput, {[}                     ;Increase brush size
    return
$^wheeldown::
    tooltip, Ctrl + Wheeldown
    ;Sendinput, {]}                     ;Reduce brush size
    return
```

Is there a way to  get AHK to "hide" the pressing or holding of `control` from the painting programme?

Comment: You say: "I have this painting program", without naming it.

Comment: Its some obsecure japanese animation/painting programme but come to think of it, I should have just mentioned its. Also Photoshop has this exact identical feature (Holding `control` temporarily activates the move tool), the programme is called [Clip Paint Studio](https://www.clipstudio.net/en/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable one of the Control keys in this program and use the other Control key to activate the move tool:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#IfWinActive ahk_exe program.exe

    ; disable the left Control key in this program 
    LCtrl::return

    ; left Control + wheel
    <^wheelup:: tooltip Ctrl + WheelUp
    <^wheeldown:: tooltip Ctrl + Wheeldown

#IfWinActive ; turn off context sensitivity
```

Replace `program.exe` with the ahk_exe of your program.